# Does Play X go into effect immediately?

Tags: fluxx

In Fluxx, the Draw X cards state that the current player may draw more cards so as to have drawn that number of cards on their turn.  Does the same thing apply to Play X?  For example, if the current Play rule is for 1 card, and the player plays a Play 2 rule, does that very play get a second play on that turn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**.

This is answered in the [online Fluxx FAQ](http://wunderland.com/LooneyLabs/Fluxx/FAQ.html):

> **Q:** Suppose the rule is Play 2 and for my second play I change the rules to Play 3. Do I play one more card or am I done because I played 2?
>
> **A:** All rules take effect immediately, so you would need to play 1 more card because the rules at that point had become Play 3.

Comment: Worth clarifying, if clarification is needed, that the reverse is also true: If the current rule is `Play 3` and your second play is `Play 1` you stop your turn immediately.